# How can I say "Today" and Yesterday" with Moment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I want this:

```
moment().format('LL');   // 4. Februar 2022
```

But if it today or yesterday it should say "Today or Yesterday" else it should display this above

Comment: You can use moment diff to check whether or not it's today or tomorrow and manually print those two cases.